# Equation for kinetic inductance and the Mattis Bardeen Formula

Tags: superconductivity

I've been reading [Tunable superconducting nanoinductors by Annunziata et al. 2010](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4187) which is a paper in which they construct inductors from ultra-thin, approximately 100 nm wide strips of niobium (Nb) and niobium nitride (NbN). These nanowires have a large kinetic inductance in the superconducting state, making them interesting for a number of applications where large inductances and low parasitic capacitances are of use (which you won't get with geometric inductance alone).

Now, in this paper they detail a number of ways of calculating the kinetic inductance $L_K$ of these inductors. One of these is equations 5 and 6, which is what my question is about. They write that one can solve for $L_K$ using BCS theory; in the low-frequency limit ($hf
\ll k_BT$), the Mattis-Bardeen formula for the complex conductivity can be written in terms of the ratio of
the imaginary conductivity $σ_2$ to the normal state conductivity $σ_n$ as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_n} = \frac{\pi\Delta}{h f}\tanh{\left(\frac{\Delta}{2k_BT}\right)}
\end{equation}

Subsequently they write that the imaginary component of the impedance is due to kinetic inductance, and that hence one can write the above equation as
\begin{equation}
L_K = \left(\frac{l}{w}\right)\frac{R_{sq}h}{2 \pi^2 \Delta}\frac{1}{\tanh{\left(\frac{\Delta}{2k_BT}\right)}}
\end{equation}
where $l$ is the length of the inductor, $w$ its width and $R_{sq}$ the sheet resistance in the normal state.

I was wondering if someone could help me understand the above; how does the second equation follow from the first? I imagine it is some combination of using the definitions of impedance and sheet resistances, but I can't manage to get there. For example the elimination of $hf$ is not obvious to me; do they use an expression for $\sigma_n$ of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the definition of the impedance of an inductor, namely $Z_L(\omega)=i\omega L_K(\omega)$.

The total impedance is $Z(\omega)=\frac{l}{w t\sigma(\omega)}$, where $l,t,w$ are the length, the thickness and the width of the wire, respectively. Here, the complex conducibility is $\sigma(\omega)=\sigma_1-i\sigma_2$ and $\omega=2\pi f$ is the angular frequency.

In a superconductor, typically, $\sigma_2\gg \sigma_1$, hence $(\sigma_1-i\sigma_2)^{-1}\approx\sigma_1/\sigma_2^2+i\sigma_2^{-1}$ and $Z(\omega)\approx R+Z_L(\omega)$, where $R=\frac{l\sigma_1}{w t\sigma_2^2}$ and $Z_L(\omega)=i\frac{l}{w t}\sigma_2(\omega)^{-1}$. Now you have to just  substitute and recall that the sheet resistance is $R_{sq}=(t\sigma_n)^{-1}$, and you should get the right result.

Try to look at this paper http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1538-3873/aabaf0/meta, page 10. I hope I haven't made any trivial mistake in the calculation.

Comment: That is great, thank you for the answer. Could one argue that $\sigma_2 \gg \sigma_1$ because in the Drude model the former the numerator is proportional to the collision time $\tau$ squared, while the latter is linear (and they have equal denominators), and this is a very long timescale $\tau \rightarrow \infty$ for superconductors?

Comment: You are welcome. I guess you can exactly argue that. There is a discussion on this in Tinkham's book-Introduction to Superconductivity-Second Edition. It should be discussed in section 2.5, which is about high frequency electrodynamics in superconductors.